# Faceted Search using php

Tags: php, mysql, faceted-search

Is there any way to do faceted search without solr, lucene etc. Only php, MySQL and Javascript. I'm trying to implement at a classifieds website, but failed. Problem is when try to filter the attributes table. structure is as follows:

table items:

```
id    description user_id
1     my car       3
2     dream car    3
3     New car      3
4     Old car      4
```

Table Meta Fields:

```
id     meta name   
 1     Make
 2     Model
 3     Color
 4     Car Type
 5     Interior Color
```

Table Item Meta:

```
item_id    field_id     meta_value
 1           1          BMW
 1           2          3Series
 1           3          White
 1           4          Coupe
 1           5          Black
 2           1          BMW
 2           2          2Series
 2           3          Black
 2           4          Coupe
 2           5          Grey
 3           1          Honda
 3           2          Civic
 3           3          Red
 3           4          Sedan
 3           5          Black
```

Now i want to filter if someone selects Black BMW, but if i use IN its giving all black or BMW. But i want same with AND condition. 
If you know faceted search then you can easily know what i mean. I want to make query to do the same with the table structure above.

```
**Addition:**
```

Also i need to show count for each attribute searched and listed. Like:

```
Make:
BMW (2)
Color:
Black(2)
White(1)
...
Car Type:
....
Interior Color:
...
```

Comment: Post your SQL. But from a design point of view, for facetted search you should have one table for each attribute (make, model, color) otherwise you'll be self joining the Table Item Meta multiple times.

Comment: @OscarM. I'm adding attributes using UI. will it be good practice to allow users to add/delete tables? while add/delete or edit an attribute? I've no idea so please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```sql
SELECT i.*, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_name = 'Make' THEN meta_value END) make,
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_name = 'Color' THEN meta_value END) color
  FROM item_meta im JOIN items i
    ON im.item_id = i.id JOIN meta m
    ON im.field_id = m.id
 GROUP BY i.id
HAVING MAX(meta_name = 'Make' AND meta_value = 'BMW') = 1
   AND MAX(meta_name = 'Color' AND meta_value = 'Black') = 1
```

Output:

```
| ID | DESCRIPTION | USER_ID | MAKE | COLOR |
|----|-------------|---------|------|-------|
|  2 |   dream car |       3 |  BMW | Black |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46a7b5/7)** demo

Comment: I was looking something like that. But problem is when i tried on my db its giving zero result. pulling my hairs.... don't know where's mistake.

Comment: Thanks,this is perfect solution. I just realized that combination i was using didn't have any item.changed the criteria and working like charm. Now how to show count of each attribute?? because it'll be for each attribute. Can you please guide me for that??

Comment: @user3727370 What do you mean by `count for each attribute`? You didn't mention it in your question...

Comment: should i have another query for it? or this same can count?

Comment: to elaborate it more by showing example you can see, ebay, amazon,sportsdirect.com etc.

Comment: have you any idea how to do it. Either with same query you mentioned or it'll be separate?

Comment: @user3727370 Here is the answer to your second question http://stackoverflow.com/a/24159732/1920232. In the meantime if my answer covered your original question please, consider to mark it as **[accepted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)**.