# Faceted Search Attribute Count

Tags: php, mysql, faceted-search

I want to have an attribute count query for following fiddle. 
[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46a7b5/10)

Its working perfect but I'm failed to count the attributes using this. Don't know how it'll be achieved because after spending many hours and changing query still its not working for me.
Anyone has suggestions??

Comment: count attributes could you please elaborate it ?

Comment: If i select Coupe and BMW then it should show no. of coupe in BMW and BMW of coupe type. SO it should result like: coupe 1 BMW 1 and others will be according to this criteria. Check the link for example: sportsdirect.com or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can this:

```sql
SELECT meta_name, meta_value, COUNT(DISTINCT item_id) count
  FROM meta m JOIN item_meta im
    ON im.field_id = m.id
 GROUP BY meta_name, meta_value
```

Output:

```
|      META_NAME | META_VALUE | COUNT |
|----------------|------------|-------|
|       Car Type |      Coupe |     2 |
|       Car Type |      Sedan |     1 |
|          Color |      Black |     1 |
|          Color |        Red |     1 |
|          Color |      White |     1 |
| Interior Color |      Black |     2 |
| Interior Color |       Grey |     1 |
|           Make |        BMW |     2 |
|           Make |      Honda |     1 |
|          Model |    2Series |     1 |
|          Model |    3Series |     1 |
|          Model |      Civic |     1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46a7b5/18)** demo

**UPDATE:**

Filtered:

```sql
SELECT meta_name, meta_value, COUNT(DISTINCT item_id) count
  FROM meta m JOIN item_meta im
    ON im.field_id = m.id
 WHERE item_id IN
(
  SELECT i.id
  FROM item_meta im JOIN items i
    ON im.item_id = i.id JOIN meta m
    ON im.field_id = m.id
 GROUP BY i.id
HAVING MAX(meta_name = 'Make' AND meta_value = 'BMW') = 1
   AND MAX(meta_name = 'Car Type' AND meta_value = 'Coupe') = 1
)
 GROUP BY meta_name, meta_value;
```

Output:

```
|      META_NAME | META_VALUE | COUNT |
|----------------|------------|-------|
|       Car Type |      Coupe |     2 |
|          Color |      Black |     1 |
|          Color |      White |     1 |
| Interior Color |      Black |     1 |
| Interior Color |       Grey |     1 |
|           Make |        BMW |     2 |
|          Model |    2Series |     1 |
|          Model |    3Series |     1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46a7b5/21)** demo

**UPDATE2:**

> Also how to handle it for same feature coming 2 times, like, i only
>   search black and red nothing else. It is currently showing no results.
>   but it should show both results. but if query is like bmw black and
>   red then it should show only bmw black or red, otherwise 0 if not
>   found

It is easy. Naturally instead of using `AND` in `HAVING` clause (a car can't be black and red at the same time) you have to use `OR` like so

```
HAVING MAX(meta_name = 'Color' AND meta_value = 'Black') = 1
    OR MAX(meta_name = 'Color' AND meta_value = 'Red')   = 1
```

or here is another way to express the same intent

```
HAVING MAX(meta_name = 'Color' AND meta_value = 'Black') +
       MAX(meta_name = 'Color' AND meta_value = 'Red') > 0
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46a7b5/28)** demo

Comment: thanks for taking interest. But this is not filtered result. Like if i select Coupe and BMW  then it should show no. of coupe in BMW and BMW of coupe type. SO it should result like: coupe 1 BMW 1 and others will be according to this criteria. Check the link for example: [link](http://www.sportsdirect.com)

Comment: this is not filtered result. Like if i select Coupe and BMW then it should show no. of coupe in BMW and BMW of coupe type. SO it should result like: coupe 1 BMW 1 and others will be according to this criteria. Check the link for example: http://www.sportsdirect.com/

Comment: it is perfect. I was counting meta values, dumb me. But its working for me with above query. Really great DBA. One last thing is, if i've to add category id then it'll be added after IN statement?

Comment: Great! I'm not quite sure what you mean by *add category id*.

Comment: I've category id in items table and in meta fields because there are other categories like, cars, bikes, boats etc. So to get attributes by category i've added a table metabycategory to make a relation with category. it has only 2 fields category id and meta id. And in items table same category is there for each item. Now when i try to put categoryid=31 in IN() statement using  above query its not running the script. showing internal server error. any thoughts..

Comment: Also how to handle it for same feature coming 2 times, like, i only search black and red nothing else. It is currently showing no results. but it should show both results.  but if query is like bmw black and red then it should show only bmw black or red, otherwise 0 if not found.

Comment: @user3727370 See update with some explanation an demo for your last follow up question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want counted but this Query counts every entry into the database: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46a7b5/15/0

Just with the COUNT() function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html